# Elasticsearch not returning partial results

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5.1

I am using `Laravel 5.1` and the `mustafaaloko/elasticquent5` package ([found here](https://github.com/mustafaaloko/elasticquent5)).

But when trying to return results, I can only get results when searching for the exact word. If I try to search part of the word, it returns nothing.

I am using `Profile::addAllToIndex();` and `dd(Profile::search(Input::get('search_term')));`

My config looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Elasticsearch Client Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array will be passed to the Elasticsearch client.
    | See configuration options here:
    |
    | http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html
    */

    'config' => [
        'hosts'     => ['ahp.dev:9200'],
        'logging'   => true,
        'logPath'   => storage_path() . '/logs/elasticsearch.log',
        'logLevel'  => Monolog\Logger::WARNING,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Index Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the index name that Elastiquent will use for all
    | Elastiquent models.
    */

    'default_index' => 'default',

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `searchByQuery` instead of `search` and use a `query_string` query

```
Profile::searchByQuery(array('query_string' => array('query' => Input::get('search_term'))));
```

Comment: I had to make an adaption by adding `'*'` before and after the `Input::get('search_term')` but then it worked! Thank you!

Comment: will accept as correct answer once waiting period is over